# Azure Service Bus: What's a 'request' and a 'message'?

Tags: azure, message-queue, servicebus, azureservicebus

In Microsoft Azure, under service bus, you can see activity graphs for the different queues/topics etc.

The graph shows various different lines, such as *incoming messages*, *outgoing messages*, *successful requests* etc.

**What is a *Request*? And what is a *Message*?**

Requests seem to be constantly occurring and often significantly large than the number of messages (in topics).  Even though the number of servers listening to the queue remains the same - sometimes the number of *requests* will dramatically increase without seeing any change in the number of *messages*.

[image: Azure Service Bus monitoring graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **assume** that a request is a poll on a queue / subscription, even if that didn't result in a message being pulled.  With the OnMessage message pump model , you typically wait 'forever' until a message arrives, resulting mostly in an equal number of receives & messages.  But when your role/thread/pump stops and restarts, that will trigger a new receive, even if no message was found.