# High number of Azure service bus incoming and successful requests

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm testing placing scheduled messages onto my Azure service bus queues. No more then 10 or so in total but it seems like the statistics in my dashboard show otherwise!

It looks like it's showing thousands of incoming requests!

Question - am I not reading the chart correctly when it says 93.63k as 93,000+ ?

[image]

Comment: I think you'll find that `Incoming Requests` is not the same metric as `Incoming Messages`.  If you share the code you're using to read from / drop messages into the queue, it might highlight this.

Comment: Refer to:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22861571/azure-service-bus-whats-a-request-and-a-message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incoming messages is the metric you need to select for determining the number of incoming messages, check the metrics list [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics#microsoftservicebusnamespaces).

As the graph by default displays the metrics of the Namespace and not the metrics of a particular Queue or Topic, the values may look high. Use dimension filter to display the metrics specific to a particular Queue or Topic.